# Compress traffic when copying a lot of files over network between two Windows server?

Tags: windows, powershell

The tools under unix/linux, e.g., scp, rsync, etc., support compression when copying files. Does any Windows (Server) tools do the compression when copying?

I will need to copy 5TB of text files which can be highly compressed.

Comment: You could use 7Zip's command line `7za` with robocopy after the file has been zipped.

Comment: But this will have two extra IO operations - compress to disk and write the zip file to remote disk before compression.

Comment: What about compressing the folder before you transfer anything. Right click / properties / advanced / Compress contents to save disk space

Comment: @MassNerder The question is not about save disk space.